# Coding a web page and cannot figure out how to center the images over the text boxes

Tags: html, css, image, textbox, center

I have tried several methods already and it doesn't change.  I have the following code.  All I need to do is center the images over the text boxes.  I cannot seem to figure it out.  ?  I tried some W3Schools and some others but whenever I try their examples, the image does not center. Here is just one image and text for an example.

```
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
       <h3 style="color:black;">APA 7th Edition. What is different? </h3>
        <style>
       .img-container {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="img-container"> <!-- Block parent element -->
         <img src="APA.jpg">

       <a href="Jobs.html">
       <p class="inset">The 7th edition APA manual has been released.  Do you know what the 
       differences are?</p>
       <p><br />

   </div>
```

Comment: is it me or there's a div wrapping half the `<head>` and all of the `<body>`, is this intended ?

Comment: Ooops, I took that out.  Still, cannot get this to center the image.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe consider to add `margin: auto` to your image. Every items that have the attribute `margin` that is set to `auto` will automatically center to the width of his container. If you also want to center the text, you could add the attribute `text-align: center` to the class of the container. Here's an example:

```css
.container{
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.images {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="images" src"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0070/7032/files/online-business-ideas.jpg?v=1576273227&width=1024" alt="images">
  <a href="#"><p>The 7th edition APA manual has been released. Do you know what the differences are?</p></a>
</div>
```